# Problems with translating special characters (ç) C# -> SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, language-translation

Don't often post. but here is a problem that I can't seem to find an answer online.

With this snippet of a C# code:

```
         if (Attributes.TryGetValue("Language", out value)) {
       if (value.ToString().Equals("French")) {
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DEFAULTLANGUAGE","Français");           
       } else {
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DEFAULTLANGUAGE","English");        
       }
```

I get this stored in the DB  FranÃ§ais instead of Français.
Can't find on the MSDN what I need to do to get the correct value.
The languages are stored in their native text, so the ç isn't going to be the only one.

*** Editing original, because replying to thread limits text length***

More details:
Ok, I should have said "Languages are stored in their native text when possible" because yes, it's just a varchar(60) not a nvarchar. I didn't think it would be a problem as ç is in the ASCII varchar list and other records have the value stored correctly.

The query isn't anything special just a standard insert into values query. (not able to display query, but it works. the record is created.) No stored proc, No specific definitions.

Comment: (Possible) side note: ["AddWithValue is Evil"](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/).

Comment: What is the data type of the column? What is the definition of the parameter? Where is the query text? Is it a stored procedure? What does that parameter definition look like? And as sticky but suggests, using AddWithValue is not great, not only because you shouldn’t let that thing decide what your data types are.

Comment: What language is your keyboard set to? The following should work for `en-US`:  `cmd.Parameters.Add("@DEFAULTLANGUAGE", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "Français";`

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Side note: When storing standard/well known country names, language names, currency prefixes, etc you should store the ISO code if one exists instead of the translated value. Example: fr-FR and en-US could be persisted and then you can use that to get the name at a later point in time in your code as needed. Same goes for countries (GB or FR or US for country codes). Although this too would fix the error you should still specify the parameter data type when using parameters and not use `.AddWithValue`.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys.. User: I tried your solution, got same results. tweaked to change the dbtype to varchar, no change.. :(   Aaron, I put your answers in the original post, but since you and Guzman say AddWithValue is evil.. I'm going to have to find a new solution.. (will read Guzmans blog next, thx Sticky)

Comment: `tweaked to change the dbtype to varchar, no change.` ← You should use `nvarchar` not `varchar`. Change both the database schema *and* specify the parameter type in the code.

Comment: Hi Igor, Yeah, changing the datatype to NVarchar isn't going to be an option for a solution, as well as changing the stored values to ISO codes as it's client configured. (They want 'English', 'Français', 'Español', etc.. that's what it is..) So, can't change schema.. I'm trying to see what parameter options to use to make it work..

Comment: Well I'll see your LOL and raise you a couple more. Wait until "they" learn about languages that use characters that don't fit into ASCII. Can you record their reaction? I wonder why `sys.syslanguages.name` is `nvarchar` instead of `varchar`? I mean, it's partly because _all names should be Unicode_, but it's also because if you limit your research to the three languages you've looked at so far, you're missing a pending time bomb. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=71c54e800d20f01b37135d13ab3d0868

Comment: Yeah, I know that in particular the Asian languages would be a problem. But like I edited before "Native language when possible".. Unfortunately, although I could change the DB type to nvarchar, I'm pretty sure that the dropdown in the application that the DB is for would fail. Which would then require at a miniumum a new product release for something that would be viewed as a 'just use the english translation'..  Thanks again for your input though, really appreciate it, also didn't know about dbfiddle.. interesting..

Answer (score 0):

*LOL*

Ok.. There will be a facepalm in here.. but I'm going to post it, because leaving this question unanswered doesn't help people.. (Science should publish their failures too.. anyways)

So, the solutions didn't work, still getting FranÃ§ais instead of Français.

Then I realized that the code file itself, could be in unicode.. and it was..
Converted it to ascii, and it changed the Français to FranÃ§ais.

Corrected the character, and with the below code the problem is fixed!

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@DEFAULTLANGUAGE",System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar,60).Value ="Français";
```

In the end I wonder why this was a problem in the first place? Ascii is wholly contained within Unicode. Why does it change?

Comment: 'ç' is NOT an ASCII character. It does, however, appear in many ANSI code pages. ASCII are the characters range in value from 0-127. ANSI codepages share these values, but add characters defined in the range 128-255. The term "ANSI codepage" is a misnomer at worst, and ambiguous at best, as there are many different code pages that people might consider "ANSI. See "Windows Code Page" on wikipedia.

Comment: What does LOL stand for?

Comment: Actually Mark it is.. #231 https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.html  Trying to make the argument that the extension is not part of the ascii table is pretty pendantic and not helpful.